# Python Socket: Can only concatenate str not bytes to str. How to encode so it won't give me this error?

Tags: python, sockets, networking

Here is my entire code: It uses user input for the **host** and the **port**.

**Server side code:**

```
import socket
import subprocess, os

print("#####################")
print("# Python Port Maker #")
print("#                   #")
print("#'To Go Boldy Where'#")
print("#  No Other Python  #")
print("#      Has Gone     #")
print("#      By Riley     #")
print("#####################")

print(' [*] Be Sure To use https://github.com/Thman558/Just-A-Test/blob/master/socket%20client.py 
on the other machine')

host = input(" [*] What host would you like to use? ")
port = int(input(" [*] What port would you like to use? "))
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  
server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1) 
server_socket.bind((host, port))

server_socket.listen(5)  
print("\n[*] Listening on port " +str(port)+ ", waiting for connections.")

client_socket, (client_ip, client_port) = server_socket.accept()
print("[*] Client " +client_ip+ " connected.\n")

while True:
try:
    command = input(client_ip+ "> ")
    if(len(command.split()) != 0):
        client_socket.send(b'command')
    else:
        continue
except(EOFError):
        print("ERROR INPUT NOT FOUND. Please type 'help' to get a list of commands.\n")
        continue

if(command == "quit"):
    break

data = client_socket.recv(1024)
print(data + "\n")

client_socket.close()
```

The error again:

```
print(:"Recieved Command : ' +command)
TypeError: can't concat str to bytes
```

It works fine when a user connects only when given commands is when this error happens not sure if it might be the `data` variable but this code just don't wanna work Lol. This is the code I am using to connect the client:

```
import socket
import subprocess, os

print("######################")
print("#                    #")
print("#     The Socket     #")
print("#     Connecter      #")
print("#                    #")
print("#     By Yo Boi      #")
print("#       Riley        #")
print("######################")

host = input("What host would you like to connect to? ")
port = int(input("What port is the server using? "))
connection_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
connection_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
connection_socket.connect((host, port))
print("\n[*] Connected to " +host+ " on port " +str(port)+ ".\n")

while True:

command = connection_socket.recv(1024)
split_command = command.split()
print("Received command : " +command)
if command == "quit":
    break

if(command.split()[0] == "cd"):
        if len(command.split()) == 1:
            connection_socket.send((os.getcwd()))
        elif len(command.split()) == 2:
            try:
                os.chdir(command.split()[1])
                connection_socket.send(("Changed directory to " +     os.getcwd()))
            except(WindowsError):
                connection_socket.send(str.encode("No such directory     : " +os.getcwd()))

else:
    proc = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True,        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout_value = proc.stdout.read() + proc.stderr.read()
    print(stdout_value + "\n")
    if(stdout_value != ""):
        connection_socket.send(stdout_value)
    else:
        connection_socket.send(command+ " does not return anything")


connection_socket.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, your script had many mistakes apart from the data type mismatch. I will tell you what was wrong with the `str` and `byte` mismatch. Whenever you convert a string to byte you must specify the encoding method. Anyway, I have fixed your script and I leave it to you to figure out the remaining things. ;)

**Server script**

```
import socket

print("#####################")
print("# Python Port Maker #")
print("#                   #")
print("#'To Go Boldy Where'#")
print("#  No Other Python  #")
print("#      Has Gone     #")
print("#      By Riley     #")
print("#####################")

print(' [*] Be Sure To use https://github.com/Thman558/Just-A-Test/blob/master/socket%20client.py on the other machine')

host = input(" [*] What host would you like to use? ")
port = int(input(" [*] What port would you like to use? "))

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server_socket.bind((host, port))

server_socket.listen(5)

print("\n[*] Listening on port " + str(port) + ", waiting for connections.")

client_socket, (client_ip, client_port) = server_socket.accept()
print("[*] Client " + client_ip + " connected.\n")

while True:
    try:
        command = input(client_ip + "> ")
        if len(command.split()) != 0:
            client_socket.send(bytes(command, 'utf-8'))
        else:
            continue
    except EOFError:
        print("ERROR INPUT NOT FOUND. Please type 'help' to get a list of commands.\n")
        continue

    if command == "quit":
        break

    data = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
    print(data + "\n")

client_socket.close()
```

**Client script**

```
import os
import socket
import subprocess

print("######################")
print("#                    #")
print("#     The Socket     #")
print("#     Connecter      #")
print("#                    #")
print("#     By Yo Boi      #")
print("#       Riley        #")
print("######################")

host = input("What host would you like to connect to? ")
port = int(input("What port is the server using? "))

connection_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
connection_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
connection_socket.connect((host, port))
print("\n[*] Connected to " + host + " on port " + str(port) + ".\n")

while True:
    print('\nWaiting for a command....')        
    command = connection_socket.recv(1024).decode()

    split_command = command.split()
    print("Received command : ", command)
    if command == "quit":
        break

    if command[:2] == "cd":
        if len(command.split()) == 1:
            connection_socket.send(bytes(os.getcwd(), 'utf-8'))
        elif len(command.split()) == 2:
            try:
                os.chdir(command.split()[1])
                connection_socket.send(bytes("Changed directory to " + os.getcwd(), 'utf-8'))
            except WindowsError:
                connection_socket.send(str.encode("No such directory     : " + os.getcwd()))

    else:
        proc = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                                stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
        stdout_value = proc.stdout.read() + proc.stderr.read()
        print(str(stdout_value) + "\n")
        if stdout_value != "":
            connection_socket.send(stdout_value)
        else:
            connection_socket.send(bytes(str(command) + ' does not return anything', 'utf-8'))

connection_socket.close()
```

> Tip: Most of the mistakes included logical flaws!

Answer (score 0):

If you print `type(data)` you will notice it is not a string but a bytes instance.
To concatenate a newline you could write this:

```
print(data + b"\n")
```

Comment: On the user machine it says this print("Received command : " +command)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str I have also posted the script I am using to connect user to host I am able to connect on the host side but when I try to say see a directory it just says b"\n"

Comment: wherever you get this error just replace the ````"..."```` with ````b"..."````

Comment: It just prints whatever is at the end of data +  if I put print(data + b"\n") it prints b"\n"

Comment: That means your data was empty

Comment: Yeah It was, it was in a string format so I had to encode all str into bytes

Answer (score 0):

`socket.recv(size)` returns a bytes object which you're trying to append to a string and that's causing the error.
You could convert the socket message to a string by doing `str(data , 'utf-8')` before appending the newline

The `print()` method adds a newline anyway so you could just write `print(data)` and that would work

Comment: It didnt give me an error but when I try to go into a directory for example it just says b' ' and then on the user machine it says "print("Received command : " +command) TypeError: can only concatenate str  (not "bytes") to str

Comment: You'll have to convert the `command` to a string or "Received command: " to bytes for this to work

Comment: Yeah I got it, I had to encode all of the str lines into bytes and that worked. Thanks!